# How to test with Mocha -Enzyme and nock , getting a file using axios.get when the reponse type is an array buffer?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, nock

I am trying to unit test a axios.get where the response is of type array buffer using mocha -enzyme nock. The test passes locally, but fails in Jenkins. what can be the reason ?

i tried increasing timeout for the get request but it dint pass.

The axios request is as follows :

```
axios.get(url, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    })
    .then((response) => {
        const fileData = {
            fileContent: Buffer.from(response.data || '', 'base64'),
            fileHeaders: response.headers
        };
        return Promise.resolve(fileData);
    });
```

and  the tests are as follows:

```
it('GETs correctly the file content as array buffer and the response headers as fileData object', (done) => {
     const fileContent = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(
                              [72, 101, 108, 108, 111,0]));
     const expectedFileData = {
        fileContent: Buffer.from(fileContent, 'base64'),
        fileHeaders: {
            "content-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "content-disposition": 'form-data; name="file";                                     filename="report_2019-07-30_2019-08-27.xls"'
        }
    };
     const scope = nock('http://localhost/')
        .defaultReplyHeaders({
            "content-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "content-disposition": 'form-data; name="file"; filename="report_2019-07-30_2019-08-27.xls"'
        })
        .get(
            '/filedownloadurl/fileId'
        )
        .reply(201, fileContent);

    getBinary(
        'http://localhost/filedownloadurl/fileId'
    ).then((response) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(response).toEqual(expectedFileData);
            scope.done();
            done();
        }, 100);
    });

});
```

Here if i log the output , response is not equal to 'expectedFileData', 
But the test passes magically locally and fails in Jenkins.  Please  suggest any other way to test this snippet or any reason test is failing only on Jenkins ?

Comment: can you confirm your version numbers for Node, axios, and nock please. And confirm that the same versions are running locally and on Jenkins.

Comment: The versions were different  from jenkins and it was updated , but unfortunately its not running still.

Comment: Can you update your question with the versions so others can help you debug?

Comment: sorry for the late reply . The problem really was a different axios version which i had. I had a more updated one than jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how a solve a similar problem: building a test using binary data with axios, jest and nock. I read the binary data from a zip file stored in my test folder.

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import nock from 'nock';
import fs from 'fs';

describe('Response binary content', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    nock('https://www.test.com')
      .get('/binary')
      .reply(200, fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/data/binary.zip`, 'binary'), {
        'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'content-length': '16563',
        'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=binary.zip',
      });
  });

  it('should handle binary files', async () => {
    const download = await Axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://www.test.com/binary',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    });
    expect(download).toBeDefined();

    expect(download.headers['content-type']).toEqual(
      'application/octet-stream',
    );
    expect(download.headers['content-length']).toEqual('16563');
  });
});
```